# Robotframework: pool.apply_async add “<?xml version=”1.0“ encoding=”UTF-8“?>” in output.xml)

Tags: robotframework, python-multiprocessing

The problem:
log.html and report.html are not created after script ends, it end with this error message:

```
[ ERROR ] Reading XML source '***/output.xml' failed: ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 1254, column 65
```

The symptom
I'm using pool.apply_async (asynchronous threading) in my python script, and found after debugging that when all threads are done "< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >" is added to output.xml (at the end of line number in the error message) which probably cause the error.

Any idea what can be done in order solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the identified XML tag or lines (in Posix systems I would use `sed -i` ), and then use `rebot` to generate the log.html and report.html.

Comment: Thanks.But i would like to know if these are known issues with RF?because it will keep occuring now and then with above scenario..so a root cause solving will be more helpful

Comment: You are using an external tool to manipulate output.xml, so that is not RF issue.

Comment: I meant to ask the main issue which is making output.xml look different??like working with python multiprocessing /threading ..does this causes known issues in RF?

Comment: Yes, I think I read somewhere that RF is not thread safe.